# pandas errors with attempt to cont unique

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying for a while but keep getting following error.
I have the following df

```
object article
aa       123     
aa       124 
ab       123
ab       123
ac       123
ac       125
ad       123
ad       125
```

what I want is:

```
object Count_unique_arcicle
aa       2
ab       1
ac       2
ad       2
```

what i get is:

```
object Count_unique_arcicle
aa      nan
ab      nan
ac      nan
ad      nan
```

Ive tried the following with no luck.

````
df= sql_query[['object ', 'article']]

df['Count_unique_arcicle'] = df['object'].groupby(df['object ']).transform('count') 

df['Count_unique_arcicle'] = df['object'].groupby(df['object']).nunique()```
````

Comment: Check second answer.

Comment: Use `df= df.groupby('object')['article'].nunique().reset_index(name='Count_unique_arcicle')`